# Unable to update to 8.0.9 with SPM

Tags: marketing-cloud, sdk

We have been including SFMC via SPM in our projects. Version 8.0.9 was released recently, but our projects, which are configured to automatically pick up these minor updates, have not picked this update up.

Looking at the repository, SPM package information is in the branch "spm" not the master branch, which is the default. There was nothing in the documentation to indicate that we need to use the spm branch instead of the default. Did someone forget to merge the branch, was the master made default by mistake, or was there a planned change to use the spm branch for publishing the SDK via SPM?

Most of the documentation regarding installing the SDK is out of date. We have followed the documentation for SPM we have found, and there is no indication we should be using a specific branch there, which leads me to believe that default branch was changed or a merge was missed.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for changes on the branch for version 8.x, you should look at the SPM branch. The master branch is for version 7.x.

Version 7.x and below of the SDK doesn't support SPM.

Comment: This is going to be a problem. Xcode allows the inclusion of an SDK by version, branch, or commit. When including by version, we can specify the version ranges we can safely autoupdate to, but must use the default branch of the repository, which is usually pointed to the main release branch. I guess previously when you set up SPM support, the default branch was set to spm. Would you restore the spm as the default for the repository so version constraints work properly?